# Delete key from hash if value is empty in Ruby

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Given:

```
data = {:a => 'A', :b => '', :c => 'C', :d => ''}
```

Objective: To remove key `:c` and `:d` if their value is an empty string. However, `:a` and `:b` should remain even if their value is an empty string. In the above example, end result should be:

```
{:a => 'A', :b => '', :c => 'C'}
```

Current approach:

```
if data[:c] == ''
  data.delete(:c)
end
if data[:d] == ''
  data.delete(:d)
end
```

Is there a better approach to get the same result? (In reality, key of type c and d is more than 10 which result in a long list of `if` checks.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [Enumerable#`each_with_object`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.1/Enumerable.html#method-i-each_with_object) to build a new hash on the fly applying your conditions:

```
data.each_with_object({}) do |(k, v), h|
  h[k] = v unless %i(c d).include?(k) && v == ''
end
#=> {:a=>"A", :b=>"", :c=>"C"}
```

As [@user000001](https://stackoverflow.com/users/828193/user000001) suggested in comments, another good option is to use [Enumerable#`reject`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.1/Enumerable.html#method-i-reject):

```
data.reject { |k, v| %i(c d).include?(k) && v == '' }
```

Comment: +1 was about to post a really similar but a bit storter asnwer: `data.reject{|k,v| [:c, :d].include?(k) && v == ''}`

Comment: The first part is super ugly (deleting hash elements with `each_with_object` is a something new in Ruby), the second is cool, thanks, @user000001 :)

Comment: Both solutions result in new object - hash. If @Ilya thinks that something gets deleted in either of these - I added link to documentation for beginners, feel free to learn what each method does and how they do not delete anything.

Comment: @Adnrey, I didn't say that it's incorrect - it's just as ugly as the instance in question :) What is the point to post this, if the author already has as clumsy solution as yours (IMO even more readable)?

Comment: what about `#empty?` instead of comparison with empty string ?)

Comment: @AlexGolubenko It is the problem of most of the answers here, they don't take corner cases into account :) `[].empty?` => `true`. Not what OP wants, even though it reads much cleaner :)

Comment: One more: the author wrote `to get the same result`. Strictly speaking (you're like  nit-picking, right?:)), your answer is wrong because you create a new object instead of mutate existing (see docs about `delete` method in the questoin)

Answer (score 4):

You can use `Hash#delete_if` method

```
unwanted_keys = [:c, :d]
hash = {:a => 'A', :b => '', :c => 'C', :d => ''}
hash.delete_if{ |k,v| unwanted_keys.include?(k) && v.blank? }
```

Hope that helps!

Answer (score 1):

you can always just iterate through the list of keys

```
KEYS_TO_DELETE_IF_BLANK = %i[c d]

KEYS_TO_DELETE_IF_BLANK.each do |key|
  data.delete(key) if data[key].blank?
end
```

Comment: not what OP wants. It clearly states: `if their value is an empty string`. `nil.blank?` => `true` (wrong). `" ".blank?` => `true` (wrong)...

Comment: it's semantics.  OP can easily change the if condition to `data[key] == ''`.  You don't necessarily need to supply the exact code.

Comment: Can agree with that. But for beginner this can look the same and later she'd find herself lost having weird bug. I think it is at least worth noting that it's not equal to initial code.

Answer (score 0):

you can just use `select` to extract hash with keys that have values

```
data = {:a => 'A', :b => '', :c => 'C', :d => ''}
data.select() {|k, v| v.present? || k == :a || k == :b }
# => => {:a=>"A", :b=>"", :c=>"C"}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also use `delete if`:

```
data = { :a => 'A', :b => '', :c => 'C', :d => '' }
data.delete_if { |k, value| %i(c d).include?(k) && value.to_s.strip == '' }
```

Comment: Note, that `delete_if` mutates the original object

Comment: It's you second answer and it is wrong again. Please, read the question carefully.

Comment: Yes, now that you've stolen the `%i(c d).include?(k)` part it became... wrong again. Why? Because you do not have `k` block variable.

Comment: Answer is still wring wrong. `" ".to_s.strip` => `""`, which is not what OP wants. It clearly states: `if their value is an empty string`. `" "` ***is not*** an empty string.

Comment: @Ilya You have ***changed*** the wrong answer leaving it wrong. I wonder what's the point of that? :)